# Deleting/Removing the first N or last N from a sprites.Group()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

So Let's say you have a sprites group and you added a bunch of things to it:

```
all_shelfs = pygame.sprite.Group()
shelf_tracking_list = []

#making shelfs
build_lvl = HEIGHT - 150
#group A
for i in xrange(100):
    wid = random.randint(120,320)
    pos = [random.randint(0, WIDTH-wid), random.randint(build_lvl-20, build_lvl), wid]
    all_shelfs.add(Shelf(pos[0],pos[1], pos[2]))
    build_lvl = build_lvl - 60

#group B
for i in xrange(100):
    wid = random.randint(120,320)
    pos = [random.randint(0, WIDTH-wid), random.randint(build_lvl-20, build_lvl), wid]
    all_shelfs.add(Shelf(pos[0],pos[1], pos[2]))
    build_lvl = build_lvl - 60
#group C
for i in xrange(100):
    wid = random.randint(120,320)
    pos = [random.randint(0, WIDTH-wid), random.randint(build_lvl-20, build_lvl), wid]
    all_shelfs.add(Shelf(pos[0],pos[1], pos[2]))
    build_lvl = build_lvl - 60

shelf_tracking_list = all_shelfs.sprites()
```

How do I delete the Group A for example?
Which was the first group I added. I noticed I can't really modify the group using this shelf_tracking_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were keeping track of the sprites *in each group*, you could use the `sprite.Group.remove(*sprites)` function to remove an entire group, as specified in the docs here: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.remove

```
# group A
group_a = list()
for i in xrange(100):
    wid = random.randint(120,320)
    pos = [random.randint(0, WIDTH-wid), random.randint(build_lvl-20, build_lvl), wid]
    new_shelf = Shelf(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2])
    group_a.append(new_shelf)
    build_lvl = build_lvl - 60
all_shelfs.add(group_a)
```

Then when you want to remove the entire group from `all_shelfs`:

```
all_shelfs.remove(group_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Since you're asking how to remove logical groups, rather than just N elements:* Depending on your program, it may greatly simplify things to put the sprite in multiple groups.

You can place a sprite in multiple groups to refer to the same sprite. Then if you `kill()` it, that **removes it from all groups**. Otherwise `remove(*groups)` for specific group removal.

```
for i in xrange(100):
    wid = random.randint(120,320)
    pos = [random.randint(0, WIDTH-wid), random.randint(build_lvl-20, build_lvl), wid]
    shelf = Shelf(pos[0],pos[1], pos[2])
    all_shelfs.add(shelf)
    shelfs_a.add(shelf)
    build_lvl = build_lvl - 60

#group B
for i in xrange(100):
    wid = random.randint(120,320)
    pos = [random.randint(0, WIDTH-wid), random.randint(build_lvl-20, build_lvl), wid]
    shelf = Shelf(pos[0],pos[1], pos[2])
    all_shelfs.add(shelf)
    shelfs_b.add(shelf)
    build_lvl = build_lvl - 60

# ...

# then to erase from both groups
for shelf in shelfs_a:
    shelf.kill()
```